# AngularJS directive initialized before resource is loaded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, promise, angularjs-resource

I have an upload directive which creates a upload url from "task.id" which is bound with:

```
scope: { id: "=" }
```

When my controller fetches data from server using angular resouce it takes some time and in that time my directive gets initialized and my id is undefined because there's no task from server yet.

I tried solving this by specifying "resolve" in my route config but unfortunately angular resouce does not provide any promise.

Is there a nice and clean solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

In your directive you could do "watch" do react when your scope.id is updated.

```
scope.$watch('id', function(){
    //Now have your directive do something, like call a server. 
});
```